# Умеренная жадность в регулярках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Думал жадность сработает на меня, но пошло что-то не так. Есть примерный код, из которого надо захватить вторую табличку. Между табличками может быть другой хтмл код, в том числе и таблички другого плана. Сейчас даже добавлю для полноты примера:

```
<p>Текст</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>разные данные</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Режим</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Тратата</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>Текст</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Время</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Тратата</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Пытался делать так^

```
<table.+?Время.+?</table>
```

Рабочий пример https://regex101.com/r/ltMG7J/2

Пытался делать позитивное заглядывание назад `(?<=...)`, но сервис матюкается на точки/плюсы внутри скобок позитивного заглядывания.

**Не получилось, вопросы**:

1) как можно выбрать табличку по примеру регулярки выше? (табличек может быть много разных, не могу привязываться к конкретным этим 3 табличкам).

2) **уже решил задачу**: как можно перекинуть вторую табличку (режим) в конец хтмл?

Comment: Первая `.+?` у вас не срабатывает так как вам надо, потому что ограничителем является `Время`, а не `</table>` для нее.

Comment: Можно сделать так https://regex101.com/r/ltMG7J/3

Comment: @Visman а как раскрыть смысл этого? `(?:(?!</?table>).)+?` ==== `.+?` но если впереди нет `</?table>`?

Comment: В `.+?` введено ограничение, чтобы внутри не было `<table>` и `</table>`. Проверка происходит при выборе каждого символа, для этого и введена группа `(?:.)+?` без обратной связи.

Comment: @Visman незахватывающий поиск это и есть без обратной связи?

Comment: Да. В результате получился посимвольный перебор, которые идет пока не найдено слово `Время` или `</?table>`.

Comment: Легкая оптимизация: https://regex101.com/r/ltMG7J/4

Comment: @ReinRaus пол миллисекунды)) а шаблон куда сложнее получился))

Comment: На текстах большого размера прирост будет  больше. Просто от делать нечего оптимизировал, ни на что не претендую.

Comment: @Visman может напишите как ответ вашу регулярку?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, оптимизация довольна важна бывает для регулярок, особенно рекурсивных.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: `(?:(?!</?table>).)+` - это [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (*"жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор*). А [тут мой ответ на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) SO. Не знаю, есть ли где-нибудь описание на русском.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ок, пасиб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой ответ из комментариев:

```
<table(?:(?!</?table>).)+?Время.+?</table>
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/ltMG7J/3

В первую `.+?` введено ограничение, чтобы внутри не было `<table>` и `</table>`. Проверка происходит при выборе каждого символа, для этого и введена группа `(?:.)+?` без обратной связи.

Оптимизированный вариант от @ReinRaus тут https://regex101.com/r/ltMG7J/4 исключает лишние проверки для символов отличных от `<` и `В`.

Comment: а где почитать про посимвольную проверку без обратной связи и другие подобные решения, о которых не пишут в популярных книгах?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, не подскажу. Просто со временем приходит понимание как можно решить ту или иную задачу. Опыт в составлении регулярок важен.

Comment: @Эдуард уже давно прочитал.